# Html attributes passing to php

Tags: php

```
Sample code from index.html file.
```

Here the content of "demo11" is available with innerHtml in the index.html based on id. After submit the form in test.php file I want to get the content of "demo11", but I am unable get it.Could you please help me.

```
<form method = "post" action="test.php" >
<table>
<tr><td id="demo11"> </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit"value="Submit"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that there is no content?

Comment: There's no form element.  HTML content isn't posted to the server, form element key/value pairs are.

Comment: The contents of a `td` element aren't posted when you submit the form. Why would they be? If you want to retrieve whatever's there, you're going to have to add an `input` tag and put the data in that or use JavaScript to grab the data *before* you submit.

Comment: In addition your input tags will need name attributes.

Answer (score 1):

It works more like so:

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="demo11" id="demo11"/> </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit"value="Submit"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The name attribute will be passed through with what ever is in the input box